# Cannot connect to X server :0.0 with a Qt application

Tags: linux, qt, x11

Compiling on Fedora 10.

I have just started my first qt GUI application. I used all the default settings.

Its just a simple form. It builds OK without any errors. But when I try and run the application. I get the following message:

```
Starting /home/rob/projects/qt/test1/test1/test1...
No protocol specified
test1: cannot connect to X server :0.0
```

Thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The general causes for this are as follows:

1. DISPLAY not set in the environment.
   **Solution**:

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0.0
   ./myQtCmdHere
   ```

   ( This one doesn't appear to be the one at fault though, as its saying which X display its trying to connect to. Also, its not always 0.0, but most of the time it is )
2. Non-Authorised User trying to run the X Application
   **Solution** ( as X owning user, ie: yourself )

   ```
   xhost +local:root   # where root is the local user you want to grant access to.
   ```

Comment: Just a quick follow-up. What does this do: export DISPLAY=:0.0 and why did my application fail because of it? Thanks,

Comment: your display interface runs a server-client model. DISPLAY tells applications where thier screen is, usually  IP:DISPLAY.SCREEN format, but without IP it uses localhost. But given the right conditions, you can 'throw' and app at any network accessible display.

Answer (score 5):

Also, if you'd like your X server to be able to receive connection over TCP, these days you must almost always explicitly enable this. To test whether you're server is allowing remote TCP connections try:

telnet 127.0.0.1 6000

If telnet is able to connect, then your X server is listening. If it can't, then neither will any remote X application and you need to enable remote TCP connections on your server.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to above answers. 
I was in a similar situation while running tests for [Code2Pdf](https://github.com/tushar-rishav/code2pdf) at travis.
I solved the problem using [xvfb-run](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xvfb-run.1.html). Quoting from the manpage,

> xvfb-run is a wrapper for the Xvfb(1x)  command  which  simplifies the task of running commands (typically an X client, or a script containing a list of clients to be run) within a virtual X server environment.

The script that I wrote was:

```
check_install_xvfb() { # check and install xvfb
    if hash xvfb-run 2>/dev/null; then
        :
    else
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get upgrade
        sudo apt-get install xvfb
    fi
}
check_install_xvfb
export DISPLAY=localhost:1.0
xvfb-run -a bash .misc/tests.sh
# .misc/tests.sh is script that runs unit tests. You can replace it with something suitable to you.
```

> Please bear with my bash code style. I am a noob bash programmer.

Running the above script helped me.
You can see the [failing build](https://travis-ci.org/tushar-rishav/code2pdf/builds/120957939) and [passing build](https://travis-ci.org/tushar-rishav/code2pdf/builds/120988164).

Hope it helps