# Capybara-webkit, rspec integration specs, and xvfb: webkit_server: Fatal IO error: client killed

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, headless, xvfb

I'm trying to get a suite of integration specs running on a ubuntu server CI box using the headless gem, xvfb, and capybara-webkit for headless testing.  Everything works beautifully on a local dev box, but things get interesting once moved over to the CI server.

In the spec helper there is a bit of code wrapping :js enabled integration specs within a headless block like so:

```
  config.around(:each, :js => true) do |example|
    Headless.ly &example 
  end
```

Like I said, this all works nicely on a local dev box.  On CI, which is using the headless gem and xvfb as the same user for tests for a different project, attempting to run the integration specs results in the following error when the spec would need to instantiate a browser instance:

> webkit_server: Fatal IO error: client killed

I've been trying to figure out what could be causing that error, but can't even find a trace of where that might have come from, or any other information to help debug the issue.

So far I've checked/tried the following:

- CI user definitely has permissions to run xvfb
- Running "Xvfb :99 -ac" as the CI user gives one warning about a not found font, no other issues

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this, or where I could look for more info?  I'm pretty stumped on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is entirely the right solution, but it seems to work for me.  Instead of doing:

```
bundle exec spec
```

Run the command with Xvfb like so, and remove the use of the headless gem:

```
xvfb-run bundle exec spec
```

Seems a bit wrong, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

for me the following worked. I am not sure why missing "-a" fails to run xvfb. My build is running @javascript tests on ubuntu+jenkins CI now

```
DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 xvfb-run -a bundle exec cucumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is related (I was using capybara-webkit instead of the Headless gem) but on my ubuntu instance (ubuntu lucid on ec2) I also needed to run:

```
sudo xhost +local:jenkins
```

to give the jenkins account permission to talk to xvfb.  See: [Cannot connect to X server :0.0 with a Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646930/cannot-connect-to-x-server-0-0-with-a-qt-application)