# How do I run python to open a browser through CRONTAB automatically?

Tags: python-2.7, cron

I've been searching on the internet but haven't found the correct answer to my question.
Here is my question in detail:

There is python opening a web browser.I can run it manually on terminal and it worked well.

But when I put it into crontab,the web browser can not be opened. This is my contab command:

```
*/1 * * * *　／usr/bin/python /home/pi/test.py 2>&1 >/dev/null | tee -a /home/pi/test.log
```

Please notice that this is a DISPLAY problem. Python was executed successfully.

I checked the log created by crontab and it says:

> Cannot connect to X server

So I tried to add env variables in my contab and changed it into:

```
*/1 * * * *　export DISPLAY=:0.0 && ／usr/bin/python /home/pi/test.py 2>&1 >/dev/null | tee -a /home/pi/test.log
```

Still it does not work. And I add something else into crontab like:

```
/usr/bin/xhost +
/usr/bin/ssh pi@localhost -X
```

But it just does not work!

Now I don't know what to do. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it and how to solve it? Thank you very much!

Sincerely,
Helen

Comment: If you solved your problem why not add your answer in the answers list instead of editing your question ?

Comment: oh I see.Thanks for your advice. @John-Philip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So excited because I solved this problem! Here's how I realised it:

I write a shell script to run python script. Here's my shell script(named"shell.sh"):

```
#！/bin/bash 
xhost +local:root 
export DISPLAY=:0.0
python /home/pi/test.py
```

Here I think xhost +local:root can also be replaced by xhost + localhost. if your user is root.

Here's my crontab command:

```
 */1 * * * *　／bin/bash /home/pi/shell.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | tee -a /home/pi/shell.log
```

Now it works perfectly!!

Anyone has the same question with me can have a look at this link: [Cannot connect to X server :0.0 with a Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646930/cannot-connect-to-x-server-0-0-with-a-qt-application)