# qt app cannot connect to x server when running with sudo in debian 10

Tags: qt, debian, x11

i have a qt app which does not start when running with sudo.
Error information is:
`No protocol specified, cannot connect to X server :0`
it was a qt4 app, and we solved the problem by adding QApplication::setGraphicsSystem("native").
But when ported to qt5, issue happens again, unfortunately setGraphicsSystem is obsolted in qt5.
I have tried several methods but none of them solves my problem:
[Cannot connect to X server :0.0 with a Qt application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646930/cannot-connect-to-x-server-0-0-with-a-qt-application)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/175611/cannot-connect-to-x-server-when-running-app-with-sudo
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118811/why-cant-i-run-gui-apps-from-root-no-protocol-specified

btw, it works fine in ubuntu20
any help is appreciated.

Regards
Herb

Comment: Rather than `sudo command ...` you could try `ssh -X localhost command ...` to enable X11 forwarding.

Comment: but my command requires elevated rights, does ssh -X work in this case?

Comment: Sorry I meant ssh as root so the command would be `ssh -X root@localhost command ...` .